# Installing Pyserial

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, python

I will be running my CNC Via Arduino UNO R3, so i have found out that it runs on GRBL and that i need to load Python and Pyserial and a graphic interface.
Loaded Python 3.5.2, no problems, opened dos window typed Python, got the python >>> prompt, so far so good, downloaded/unzipped/copy/paste Pyserial  into c:/python35/lib/site-packages/pyserial.
at this point, at the dos prompt i type >>>python setup.py install. All i get is a syntax error.

I have included the dos script for comment

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Goblin>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\Goblin'
>>> os.chdir("/users/")
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\users'
>>> os.chdir("/../")
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\'
>>> os.chdir("/python35/lib/site-packages/pyserial/")
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pyserial'
>>> python setup.py install
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python setup.py install
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

This is about the 7th attempt.
I seem to be following the instruction correctly but it wont install ....HELP Please, this is so frustrating, what have I done wrong.
Thanks in advance
Doug

Comment: Dont do this within the python environment. Its meant to be run from the system command line. Navigate with 'cd' in Command Prompt to the pyserial folder and then run this command again.

Answer (score 2):

not exactly related to Arduino but here it goes...

First check if you have pip installed:

```
pip --version
```

**if not installed** go [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and download the get-pip script.
then on directory where you saved get-pip run on console:

```
python get-pip.py
```

this will install pip into your system which makes installation of packages in python way more easy.

if installed but not latest version ( at momment 8.1.2) do an upgrade before:

> On Linux or OS X:

```
pip install -U pip
```

> On Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

after install pyserial using pip:

```
pip install pyserial
```

**Did it work?** 
If not, try:

```
python -m pip install pyserial
```

**if it still doesn't work** install from source. Get the latest version [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) extract it and in the dir where you extrated run:

```
python setup.py install
```

PS: change to dir first, no need to do it inside python.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that what you are trying to do is actually call 'python setup.py' within the python script itself. Which you cannot do. The easiest way to install pyserial is via pip like so. (Windows)

```
python -m -U pyserial --upgrade
```

Now if you still want to use setup.py or you don't have pip installed. Make sure that you meet all of the package dependencies. Which in pyserial there are no others. Try exiting out of the python interpreter and just running

```
python setup.py install
```

In the same folder location as the extracted zip (use cd to change directories)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All...by running the command at a std DOS prompt I was able to install the Pyserial.py file.
i have since seen comments that some of the 3.x.x series Python has glitches,(I am running Windows7). I have gone to 2.7 Python as a program i would like to use doesn't appear to run under 3.x.x   bCNC likes the earlier versions, not sure why, but it does run under 2.7  . for those interested JCNC, EFL CNC, Grbl Controller seem to run OK under 3.x.x